# How to use stringbuider to send HTML as Body?

Tags: java, stringbuilder

Updated code for assistance with as requested.

```
buffer.append("\n\nBe sure to activate your account, by ");
    buffer.append("<a href=\"")
        .append(url)
        .append("activateAccount.do?clientId=")
        .append(client.getId())
        .append("&activationCode=")
        .append(client.getActivationCode())
        .append("&mat=").append(mobileApplicationType)
            .append("\">");[enter image description here][1]
            .append("clicking here")</a>;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "This didn't work"? Were there any error messages? if yes, please include them in your question or otherwise elaborate on what didn't work

Comment: Thank you @Togira. What didn't work is that it's taking a plain string
when it should treat the html string. I had put the static link but this one is also not working

Comment: I would like to add href tag but it takes as plain string not as a link.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem doesn't lie in the StringBuilder, but in the fact, that you miss quotes around the link. (At least at the beginning)

And remember that you can chain the calls to StringBuilder.

```java
buffer.append("<a href=\"")
    .append(url)
    .append("activateAccount.do?clientId=")
    .append(client.getId())
    .append("&activationCode=")
    .append(client.getActivationCode())
    .append("&mat=").append(mobileApplicationType)
    .append("\">")
    .append("clicking here")
    .append("</a>");
```

And please don't concatenate String in the append call for StringBuilder!

On a side note, when you notice, that you are doing multiple things at the same time, try to extract some functions from it. For example, the concatenation of the URL could be a separate function.

```java
public String getActivationHTML() {
    var buffer = new StringBuilder();
    buffer.append("\n\nBe sure to activate your account, by ");
    buffer.append("<a href=\"")
            .append(buildUrl(url, client, mobileApplicationType))
            .append("\">")
            .append("clicking here")
            .append("</a>");
    return buffer.toString();
}

private String buildUrl(String url, Client client, AppType mobileApplicationType) {
    var buffer = new StringBuilder();
    buffer.append(url)
            .append("activateAccount.do?clientId=")
            .append(client.getId())
            .append("&activationCode=")
            .append(client.getActivationCode())
            .append("&mat=")
            .append(mobileApplicationType);
    return buffer.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you @valerij-dobler. Struggling to get it to work still. Can you please amend the code I provided and I will try copying it in? Thank you so much.

Comment: I used your example above and still having the same issue. I cant screenshot and attach but would like to show you the output.

Comment: This was the only obvious error you've made. Maybe another error lies in the variables you template in? To debug it further you could create a variable with the whole URL and take a look while debugging through it.

Comment: The link works fine without the concatenating which I have implemented so thank you for that, but my issue now is that it shows like this: Be sure to activate your account, by <a href="URL"> URL is where the stringbuilder creates and I have removed from the example.

Comment: Instead of the URL being hidden and only showing the words "click here", it seems to have kept the URL showing.

Comment: This is what I have for now:  buffer.append("\n\nBe sure to activate your account, by ");
  buffer.append("<a href=\"")
      .append(url)
      .append("activateAccount.do?clientId=")
      .append(client.getId())
      .append("&activationCode=")
      .append(client.getActivationCode())
      .append("&mat=").append(mobileApplicationType)
    .append("clicking here");
      .append("\">");

Comment: Update your question rather than pasting long code in comments.

Comment: I have done this for you now Valerij. Sorry, new to StackOverflow :)

Comment: Also, `&` must be written as `&amp;` (or `&#38;`).

Comment: What VGR writes is also important. Make sure you properly HTML escape your inputs.

Comment: The actual URL is working fine, it is just that instead of seeing the URL we want text that is hyperlinked instead. +

Comment: And I think you now don't close it with </a>.

Comment: Meaning the line `.append("\">");` should be before the "click me" text. And after the text there should be an `</a>`

Comment: I have updated the code in the question for you again, is this ok now?

Comment: That is not valid Java code. By "after the text should be an <a?>" I meant, you should append a string containing it to the string builder. Don't you use an IDE for your programming?

Comment: I use Atom. Can you please amend the code so it is valid so I can see where I am going wrong? Thank you

Comment: I already did. Check my answer.

Comment: Try Eclipse or IntelliJ IDEA Community. Both are free to use and give you a lot more feedback when writing Java code.

Comment: The deployment through up loads of errors when I changed it to your answer. Oops.

Comment: It seems to have worked now, it didnt like the public and private strings.

Comment: Testing if it worked now.

Comment: `public` and `private` are access modifiers.

Comment: It deployed but did not work, I have attached an image to the question so you can see the output. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vw7ox.png

Comment: It seems to be escaping the HTML from the string builder. Especially the chevrons.

Comment: Yes, that is the issue I am trying to fix.

Comment: The issue doesn't lie in the StringBuilder. It has to do with the code which receives the StringBuilder (or the content from it).

Comment: Ok, so how do I fix that?

Comment: Try to understand where the real problem originates from. It seems, that you are using Struts. Maybe taking a look into the documentation would help.

Comment: Tried. Can't work it out hence the question on this platform? You given up helping me get this sorted :) :)

Comment: Well, what you've shared with us is not a [minimal reproduceable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Either you try to follow the flow of data on your own or share with us more code which is executed on that StringBuilder content. Either way, I think this question is answered and sadly should be removed because it doesn't adhere to the rules of being minimal & reproducable.